# Fixing configuration inspector missing schema errors

Tags: 8, configuration

I'm using the configuration inspector to fix schema issues before I put a module live as a full release.

I'm finding the following error, but I'm unclear on how to fix it.

The module provides a new entity type, private_message. In config/install, I have the file:

*core.entity_form_display.private_message.private_message.default.yml*

This file has the following contents (trimmed):

```
content:
  message:
    type: string_textarea
    label: hidden
    settings:
      placeholder: Message
      rows: 5
    region: content
    third_party_settings: {  }
    weight: null
```

The configuration inspector for core.entity_form_display.private_message.private_message.default is telling me that the schema for content.message.label has a missing schema:

> content.message.label     Undefined   undefined   hidden  missing schema

In the raw data for the inspection, I see:

```
'core.entity_form_display.private_message.private_message.default:content.message.label' => 'missing schema',
```

Does anyone know how I can fix this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, remove that line. Form displays have no label control, only view displays do. Maybe this was copy & pasted somehow by hand when creating that config.

Comment: Thanks, that did it. Not sure how it got in there, but removing it solved it. Much appreciated.